# Computing sum of a dataframe and appending it at the top

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, append

Here's a sample dataframe. Set_index was used to set Constraint_ID as the index, which mis-aligns with the rest of the columns.

What I want is to put the sum of the TotalSP, Onpeak and Offpeak in the spaces just below (spaces that got created due to the misalignment). Is that possible? If not, can I create another row just below the columns labels that shows the totals of the columns?

```
         Constraint Name    TotalSP       Onpeak    Offpeak
Constraint_ID               
77127   aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  -2174.5     -2027.21    -147.29
98333   bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb  -1180.62    -1180.62     0
1049    cccccccccccccccccc  -1036.53    -886.77     -149.76
```

Comment: You want the sums to become another row of the dataframe? What will be the Constraint_ID and Constraint Name of the new row?

Comment: DZY - no constraint_ID for that row. Constraint Name to be the count of the constraint name column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can compute the sum with `df.sum`:

```
In [189]: df2 = df.iloc[:, 1:].sum().to_frame().T.rename({0 : 'sum'}); df2
Out[189]: 
     TotalSP  Onpeak  Offpeak
sum -4391.65 -4094.6  -297.05
```

Next, you can concatenate it with your first dataframe using `pd.concat`:

```
In [191]: pd.concat([df2, df])
Out[191]: 
          Constraint Name  Offpeak   Onpeak  TotalSP
sum                   NaN  -297.05 -4094.60 -4391.65
77127  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa  -147.29 -2027.21 -2174.50
98333  bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb     0.00 -1180.62 -1180.62
1049   cccccccccccccccccc  -149.76  -886.77 -1036.53
```

Disclaimer, I don't recommend this unless you just want to write this to a csv.

Comment: Thanks. Under the constraint name where sum is NaN, how could i get the count?

Comment: @ShyamaSonti For this example, you want the count as 3?

Comment: @ShyamaSonti This will do it: `df3 = pd.concat([df2, df]); df3.loc['sum', 'Constraint Name'] = len(df)`